# Xvnc process at 100% CPU when idle

Tags: select, vnc

I have a very annyoing problem when running TigerVNC 1.3.1 in a Debian 7 virtual machine. After about one minute doing nothing in the VNC window, the Xvnc process goes up to 100% CPU usage. Once I move my mouse into the VNC window again, the CPU usage returns to normal. I believe that the function call select() is the culprit. Doing an "strace -p " gives me tons of this:

```
select(256, [0 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
```

And "strace -c -p ":

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 78.19    0.001760           0     98445           select
 21.81    0.000491           0    196889           setitimer
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.002251                295334           total
```

I'm not an expert on system function calls, but all other processes I checked with these commands do not show that kind of behavior. Is it a bug in the tigervnc code or is there a way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you reset to default settings to see if everything becomes fine. I was a tightvnc user for a long time, until I switched to RealVNC (free edition). I'd suggest you give a try of it. The settings are almost identical to tightvnc. And it supports real cross machine text copy-and-paste.

Comment: I tried RealVNC. It's unusuable for me b/c the keyboard layout panel in KDE crashes with it, so I'm unable to use non-U.S. keys.